# Long response time when exception is thrown

Tags: c#, exception

There are 3 layers in the application.

- Api
- Application
- Infrastructure

**Test 1**

An application level exception is thrown.

*here are the codes*

**Api**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
 {
     await _app.Handler();
 }
```

**Application**

```
 public async Task Handler()
 {
     throw new NotFoundException();
 }

 public class NotFoundException : Exception
 {
     public NotFoundException()
         : base($"Product not found.")
     {
     }
 }
```

**Infrastructure**

```
 public async Task Service()
 {
     return null;
 }
```

*Here is the result*

Exception thrown: 'Application.Exceptions.NotFoundException' in Application.dll

Exception thrown: 'Application.Exceptions.NotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Response Time 400ms between 500ms

**Test 2**

An infrastructure level exception is thrown.

*here are the codes*

**Api**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
 {
     await _app.Handler();
 }
```

**Application**

```
 public async Task Handler()
 {
     return null;
 }
```

**Infrastructure**

```
 public async Task Service()
 {
     throw new NotFoundException();
 }
 
 public class NotFoundException : Exception
 {
     public NotFoundException()
         : base($"Product not found.")
     {
     }
 }
```

*Here is the result*

Exception thrown: 'Infrastructure.Exceptions.NotFoundException' in Infrastructure.dll

Exception thrown: 'Infrastructure.Exceptions.NotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Exception thrown: 'Infrastructure.Exceptions.NotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Response Time 800ms between 900ms

**Question**

why response time increases?

is this a usual thing?

Comment: It is due to the c# managed library.  A c# application put a default exception handler at root of code.  When an exception occurs the managed library goes up the execution (to ancestor methods) finding the first exception handle.  Since you do not have exception handles the mores nested calls your application has the longer it will take to report the exception.

Comment: Where is `catch`? Or the question should be "why my app crashes slowly?"